# Windsor IoC Sample Help - "HttpServiceWatcher& which was not registered."

Tags: vb.net, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I'm following the [Windsor Inversion of Control (IoC) Getting Started example](http://www.castleproject.org/container/gettingstarted/part1/code.html), which is in C#, but I'm implementing it in VB.Net, and I've run into a small problem..

Here's the exception I'm getting in full:

> Can't create component 'form.component' as it has dependencies to be satisfied. 
>   form.component is waiting for the following dependencies:
>
> Services: 
>   - InversionOfControl.HttpServiceWatcher& which was not registered.

but I think I am registering it - it's the first one registered!

I'm using VB 8 (Visual Studio 2005 / .Net 2.0), and [Windsor 1.0 RC3](http://www.castleproject.org/castle/download.html).

---

Here's my **App.vb**:

```
Imports Castle.Windsor

Public Class App

    Public Shared Sub Main()

        Dim container As New WindsorContainer

        'register the components
        container.AddComponent("httpservicewatcher", _
           GetType(HttpServiceWatcher))
        container.AddComponent("email.notifier", GetType(IFailureNotifier), _
           GetType(EmailFailureNotifier))
        container.AddComponent("alarm.notifier", GetType(IFailureNotifier), _
           GetType(AlarmFailureNotifier))
        container.AddComponent("form.component", GetType(Form1))

        'request the component from the container
        Dim aForm As Form = container(GetType(Form1))

        'use it!
        Application.Run(aForm)

        'release it
        container.Release(aForm)

    End Sub

End Class
```

**Form1**

```
Public Class Form1

    Private oServiceWatcher As HttpServiceWatcher

    Sub New(ByRef ServiceWatcher As HttpServiceWatcher)

        ' This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        Me.oServiceWatcher = ServiceWatcher
    End Sub
End Class
```

**HttpServiceWatcher**

```
Public Class HttpServiceWatcher

    Private oNotifier As IFailureNotifier

    Sub New(ByRef Notifier As IFailureNotifier)
        oNotifier = Notifier
    End Sub

    Sub StartWatching()

        'should start a thread to ping the service
        'if (pingresult = Failed)
        oNotifier.Notify()
        'end if

    End Sub

    Sub StopWatching()

        'stop thread

    End Sub

End Class
```

**IFailureNotifier**

```
Public Interface IFailureNotifier

    Sub Notify()

End Interface
```

**AlarmFailureNotifier** and **EmailFailureNotifier** both implement IFailureNotifier but the `Notify()` methods are empty

---

I've tried changing the order by putting the IFailureNotifier's first, HttpServiceWatcher 3rd and Form last but I get the same error.

I've done a Clean and rebuild, but I get the same error.

I'm obviously new to this (as I'm going through the 'Getting Started'), can you point out what I've missed please?

Thank you  :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a VB wiz, but I suspect the problem is the ByRef keyword in the New sub. Try changing it to:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private oServiceWatcher As HttpServiceWatcher

    Sub New(ServiceWatcher As HttpServiceWatcher)

        ' This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        Me.oServiceWatcher = ServiceWatcher
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip - when I removed the 'ByRef' it got replaced with 'ByVal' (I thought it had to be one or the other, but I gave it a try with nothing anyway!), and I changed both constructors in the project: Form1 and HttpServiceWatcher, and that sorted it. Thanks again :o)